# Conflict with mod_rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

How can I rewrite
www.mysite.com/login to www.mysite.com/login.php
along with several other site pages like "search" and "signup", etc?

I tried to do this with

```
RewriteRule ^(.+). $1.php [R,NC]
```

but got a really nasty redirect loop instead. :/

I also would like to rewrite
www.mysite.com/Elvis to www.mysite.com/profile?username=Elvis
which I'm sure conflicts with the first rule.

Is this possible?

Comment: you want to redirect everything to their respective file .php?

Comment: The URI `/profile.php` (for example) matches your regex.  You'll need to change your regex or add other rewrite rules that stop processing for the pages you don't want redirected.

Comment: @BookOfZeus Yes, except the user name which should redirect to profile which should redirect to profile.php.

Comment: please read Gian  comment, or can you have something like: /profile/Elvis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's something that should work:

```
# if the URL doesn't end with "php":
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)\.php$
# then whatever it is, add php at the end:
RewriteRule (.+) $1.php [NC]
```

Your errors are:

- directive R = force redirect = it will redirect the client browser to the new and the client will see this (URL and I suppose that's not what you want to do)
- The **`^`** and the **`.`** are useless and (maybe) produce errors.

If that doesn't work, it's probably very close to what you want.

### Two hints:

---

Please try to use the `RewriteLog` directive: it helps you to track down such problems:

```
# Trace:
# (!) file gets big quickly, remove in prod environments:
RewriteLog "/web/logs/mywebsite.rewrite.log"
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteEngine On
```

---

My favorite tool to check for regexp:

http://www.quanetic.com/Regex (don't forget to choose ereg(POSIX) instead of preg(PCRE)!)

Comment: Been trying out the error logging.  Why do I keep receiving Server Error 500 and `RewriteLog not allowed here` in the Apache log?

Comment: Add "AllowOverride All" for this directory in your *global* configuration. Restart your server. This should work. But **don't forget to remove this directive once in a prod environment**.